# What happens when an Undying creature goes to the graveyard from the deck or hand?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens when you discard a creature(with Undying) from your hand to the graveyard? Does it go to the Battlefield (without summoning sickness)?

And what happens if I use [Mulch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mulch) and put all Undying creatures in the graveyard? The same?

Comment: Good question, welcome to the site! :D

Answer (score 6):

**No, sorry.**

The fine print on the cards tell us what we need to know:

> Undying (When this creature dies, if it had no +1/+1 counters on it,
>   return it to the battlefield under its owner's control with a +1/+1
>   counter on it.)

"Dies" refers to "goes to the graveyard from the battlefield." Thus, **a creature card that is placed into the graveyard from any other zone doesn't trigger undying**.

Since Undying doesn't say anything specific about "summoning sickness" or haste, the regular rules apply. Namely:

> 302.6. A creature’s activated ability with the tap symbol or the untap symbol in its activation cost can’t    be activated unless the
>   creature has been under its controller’s control continuously since
>   his or her    most recent turn began. A creature can’t attack unless
>   it has been under its controller’s control    continuously since his
>   or her most recent turn began. This rule is informally called the
>   “summoning    sickness” rule.

It doesn't matter where the creature came from: if it didn't start the turn no the field under your control, it still has "summoning sickness".

Comment: Thank you for anwsering and explain me so well! Big thanks! I think now I have to think again about some ideas on the deck I was making. :(

Comment: Also, welcome to the site.

Comment: You might also add that going to any zone from the battlefield **except** the graveyard doesn't constitute dying as well.  For example, exiling a creature wouldn't allow it to come back with the counter.